# How to get string value from glib::Variant with VariantType 'ay'?

Tags: rust, gtk, gtk3

I have this rust code for a gtk application. `args` is a `glib::Variant`.

```
gtk_app.connect_handle_local_options( move |_, args| {
  match glib::VariantTy::new("ay") {
    Ok(v) => {
      if let Some(cfg) = args.lookup_value("config", Some(&v)) {
        println!("ok {:?}", cfg);
        if let Some(value) = cfg.get::<String>() {
          println!("value {:?}", value);
        }
      }
    }
    Err(e) => {
      println!("error {:?}", e);
    }
  }
}
```

variable `cfg` is

```
Variant { ptr: 0x5571b47a6e10, type: VariantTy { inner: "ay" }, value: "b\'/config.json\'" }
```

How do I get the string value?

Answer (score 0):

`ay` is a byte array, not a string. You can get the contained value in that variant as a `Vec<u8>` via

```rust
let byte_array = variant.get::<Vec<u8>>().expect("not a byte array");
```